# Set theory - Cartesian product of family

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the cartesian product of a family.

I understand if $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $Y = \{4,5,6\}$ then the cartesian product of these two sets is $\{(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)\}$

If ($X_{i}$} is a family of sets where $i \in I$, the Cartesian product of the family is, by definition, the set of all families $x_{i}$ with $x_{i} \in X_{i}$  where each $i \in I$

Say I = $\{1,2,3\}$ and $X_{i} = \{4,5,6\}$ How can you have a cartesian product of 1 set?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $X_1, X, X_i$ ?

Comment: See the following post about [Cartesian products of families](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177357/cartesian-products-of-families-in-halmos-book).

Comment: We have an *index* set $I$ and and a "family" of sets $\{ X_i \}$. The *cartesian product* of the family is the set of all families $\{ x_i \}$ with $x_i ∈ X_i$ for each $i \in I$.

Comment: If $I$ is a $3$ elements set, each element of the cartesian product will be a $3$-uple : $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ where $a_i \in X_i$.

Comment: So the cartesian product is I times X?

Comment: No; it is $X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3$.

Comment: So in Halmo's definition each xi is equal to the same set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{4,5,6\}$ and $X_1=X_2=X_3=X$. Then

$X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3=\{(a,b,c): a,b,c \in X\}$.

Comment: I'm confused. Why X1=X2=X3=X?

Comment: @Paul: Because you said $X_i = \{ 4,5,6\}$ for all $i$.

Comment: so is the cartesian product something like {(4,4,4),(,4,4,5),(4,4,6),(4,5,4),(4,5,5).....?

Comment: Yes. The cartesian product has $27$ elements.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, but what would I be in your example? {1,2,3}?

Comment: Yes, $I=\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: So if x1=8,x2=9 and x3=10 the Cartesian product would be {(8,9,10)}?

Comment: Your $x_i$ are numbers and not sets ! If $X_1=\{8\}, X_2=\{9\}$ and $X_3=\{10\}$, then we have $X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3=\{(8,9,10)\}$.

Comment: Sorry that’s what I meant. When can Xi ever be a set with more than 1 element? When a set contains another set?