# Explanation for Cartesian Product of a Family

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm currently reading Naive Set Theory by P. R. Halmos, and am stuck on the way he defines the cartesian product of a family. He wrote: "If $X_i$ is a family of sets ($i$ belongs to $I$), the Cartesian Product of the family is, by definition, the set of all families $x_i$ with $x_i$ belonging to $X_i$, for each $i$ in $I$. Could anyone guide me through this and perhaps give an example? Thank you in advance

Comment: What is $A \times B$? It is the set of pairs $\{ (a,b) \mid a \in A \text { and } b \in B \}$. Thus, if we generalize the operation to a family $\{ X_i \}$ what we get is a set of $i$-uples $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n, \ldots )$ (we are not restricting the index set $I$ to be *finite*) where $x_i \in X_i$. The issue is that we cannot write uples of "unspecified" length...

Comment: Thus, we start from the formal definition of *family* as a function $f. I \to X$ where $f= \{ (i,x) \mid x \in X \}$ and we rename the pair $(i,x)$ as $x_i$. Thus: $f= \{ x_i \}$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177357/cartesian-products-of-families-in-halmos-book).

Comment: The last point to be considered is that an index set $I$ is not necessarily ordered: thus, the notation $(x_i), i\in I$ is not well-defined if we try to define it as $(x_1,x_2, \ldots)$; we have instead $\{ x_i \} = \{ (i,x) \}$.