# Cartesian Product of Families question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

What does A<sub>0</sub> × A<sub>1</sub> mean? If A<sub>0</sub> is the set {a} and A<sub>1</sub> is {c}. Then is A<sub>0</sub> × A<sub>1</sub> the set {{(0,a),(1,a)},{(0,a),(1,b)},{(0,b),(1,a)},{(0,b),(1,b)}} or the set {(a,b)}?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartesian products of families in Halmos' book.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177357/cartesian-products-of-families-in-halmos-book)

Answer (score 1):

Is there *any* element called "o" , or "1" in any of your sets? No, there is not. Thus, in your example

$$\;A\times B=\{a\}\times\{c\}=\{ (a,c)\}\;$$

...and that's all. By definition, the cartesian product $\;A\times B\;$ is the set of all *ordered* couples

$\;(x,y)\;$ , when $\;x\in A\,,\,\,y\in B\;$ .